# Depending on the zoom, my divs overlap differently...really bizarre (all browsers)

Tags: css, html, zooming, fadeout

http://www.kikbo.com/secret/about.html

This is breaking my balls...depending on the level of zoom used by the browser, my boxes don't line up and it winds up looking like shit (in all browsers). Any suggestions? Could I be doing this more easily with jQuery?

HTML

```
</div>
<div class="tile" id = 'tile1' onmouseover="this.style.color = 'grey'" onmouseout="this.style.color = 'black'" onclick="fadeOutNoDisplay(this.id,100);"><br><br>CPSIA</div>
<div class="tile" id = 'tile2' onmouseover="this.style.color = 'grey'" onmouseout="this.style.color = 'black'" onclick="fadeOutNoDisplay(this.id,100);"><br><br>Drugs</div>
<div class="tile" id = 'tile3' onmouseover="this.style.color = 'grey'" onmouseout="this.style.color = 'black'" onclick="fadeOutNoDisplay(this.id,100);"><br><br>Robots</div>
<div class="tile" id = 'tile4' onmouseover="this.style.color = 'grey'" onmouseout="this.style.color = 'black'" onclick="fadeOutNoDisplay(this.id,100);"><br>The<br>Kikbo<br>Story<br></div>
<div class="tile-right" id = 'tile5' onmouseover="this.style.color = 'grey'" onmouseout="this.style.color = 'black'" onclick="fadeOutNoDisplay(this.id,100);"><br>What's with the crazy colors?</div>
<div class="tile" id = 'tile6' onmouseover="this.style.color = 'grey'" onmouseout="this.style.color = 'black'" onclick="fadeOutNoDisplay(this.id,100);">Are Kikbos available outside the United States?</div>
<div class="tile" id = 'tile7' onmouseover="this.style.color = 'grey'" onmouseout="this.style.color = 'black'" onclick="fadeOutNoDisplay(this.id,100);"><br><br>hello!</div>
<div class="tile" id = 'tile8' onmouseover="this.style.color = 'grey'" onmouseout="this.style.color = 'black'" onclick="fadeOutNoDisplay(this.id,100);"><br><br>hello!</div>
<div class="tile" id = 'tile9' onmouseover="this.style.color = 'grey'" onmouseout="this.style.color = 'black'" onclick="fadeOutNoDisplay(this.id,100);"><br><br>hello!</div>
<div class="tile-right" id = 'tile10' onmouseover="this.style.color = 'grey'" onmouseout="this.style.color = 'black'" onclick="fadeOutNoDisplay(this.id,100);"><br>Where can I get my very own Kikbo?</div>
<div class="tile-bottom" id = 'tile11' onmouseover="this.style.color = 'grey'" onmouseout="this.style.color = 'black'" onclick="fadeOutNoDisplay(this.id,100);"><br><br>hello!</div>
<div class="tile-bottom" id = 'tile12' onmouseover="this.style.color = 'grey'" onmouseout="this.style.color = 'black'" onclick="fadeOutNoDisplay(this.id,100);"><br><br>hello!</div>
<div class="tile-bottom" id = 'tile13' onmouseover="this.style.color = 'grey'" onmouseout="this.style.color = 'black'" onclick="fadeOutNoDisplay(this.id,100);"><br><br>hello!</div>
<div class="tile-bottom" id = 'tile14' onmouseover="this.style.color = 'grey'" onmouseout="this.style.color = 'black'" onclick="fadeOutNoDisplay(this.id,100);"><br><br>hello!</div>
<div class="tile-bottom-right" id = 'tile15' onmouseover="this.style.color = 'grey'" onmouseout="this.style.color = 'black'" onclick="fadeOutNoDisplay(this.id,100);"><br><br>hello!</div>
<div class="tile-small"><br><br>CPSIA</div>
<div class="tile-small"><br><br>Ë¼½Ý</div>
<div class="tile-small"><br><br>RobsdfsdafotsÊ®´ó¸»ÉÌ´ó·¨Ê¦´ó·¨</div>
<div class="tile-small">Founded in Jan 2010, our mission is to entrench Kikbo Kick Shuttlecocks</div>
<div class="tile-right-small">There are six buttons up top and six feathers in every pack. The probability of each color appearing is the same for the buttons as it is for the feathers. <a href="javascript:colorize()">Try for yourself.</a></div>
<div class="tile-small"><br><br>nope.</div>
<div class="tile-small"><br><br>helasflo!</div>
<div class="tile-small"><br><br>helasdflo!</div>
<div class="tile-small"><br><br>hello!</div>
<div class="tile-right-small"><br><br>nowhere.</div>
<div class="tile-bottom-small"><br><br>asdfas</div>
<div class="tile-bottom-small"><br><br>hellasdfo!</div>
<div class="tile-bottom-small"><br><br>hello!</div>
<div class="tile-bottom-small"><br><br>hello!</div>
<div class="tile-bottom-right-small"><br><br>hello!</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.tile {
width: 192px;
height: 192px;
background-color: white;
border-color: grey;
border-style: solid;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-top-width: 1px;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px;
float: left;
font: 30px "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
z-index: 2;
position: relative;
}

div.tile:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}

div.tile-right{
width: 192px;
height: 192px;
background-color: white;
border-color: grey;
border-style: solid;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-top-width: 1px;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px;
float: left;
font: 30px "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
z-index: 2;
position: relative;
}

div.tile-right:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}

div.tile-bottom {
width: 192px;
height: 192px;
background-color: white;
border-color: grey;
border-style: solid;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-top-width: 1px;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px;
float: left;
font: 30px "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
z-index: 2;
position: relative;
}

div.tile-bottom:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}

div.tile-bottom-right{
width: 192px;
height: 192px;
background-color: white;
border-color: grey;
border-style: solid;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-top-width: 1px;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px;
float: left;
font: 30px "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
z-index: 2;
position: relative;
}

div.tile-bottom-right:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}

div.tile-small {
width: 192px;
height: 192px;
background-color: white;
border-color: grey;
border-style: solid;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-top-width: 1px;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px;
float: left;
font: 15px "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
z-index: 1;
position: relative;
top: -580px;
}

div.tile-right-small{
width: 192px;
height: 192px;
background-color: white;
border-color: grey;
border-style: solid;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-top-width: 1px;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px;
float: left;
font: 15px "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
z-index: 1;
position: relative;
top: -580px;
}

div.tile-bottom-small {
width: 192px;
height: 192px;
background-color: white;
border-color: grey;
border-style: solid;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-top-width: 1px;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px;
float: left;
font: 15px "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
z-index: 1;
position: relative;
top: -580px;
}

div.tile-bottom-right-small{
width: 192px;
height: 192px;
background-color: white;
border-color: grey;
border-style: solid;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-top-width: 1px;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px;
float: left;
font: 15px "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
z-index: 1;
position: relative;
top: -580px;
}
```

Javascript

```
document.write("<style type='text/css'>#big-pic {visibility:hidden;} </style>");
document.write("<style type='text/css'>#gallery {visibility:hidden;} </style>");

function startFade(objId,x) {
  obj = document.getElementById(objId);
  if (x == 'in') {
  setOpacity(obj, 0);
  obj.style.visibility = 'visible';
  fadeIn(objId,0);
  }
  else if (x == 'out') {
  setOpacity(obj, 100);
  fadeOut(objId,100);
  }
  else {
  alert('You must set x to "in" or "out"');
  }
}

function setOpacity(obj, opacity) {
  opacity = (opacity == 100)?99.99999999999:opacity;

  // IE4,5,6,7
  obj.style.filter = "alpha(opacity:"+opacity+")";

  // Safari<1.2, Konqueror
  obj.style.KHTMLOpacity = opacity/100;

  // Older Mozilla and Firefox
  obj.style.MozOpacity = opacity/100;

  // Safari 1.2, newer Firefox and Mozilla, CSS3
  obj.style.opacity = opacity/100;

}

function fadeIn(objId,opacity) {
  if (document.getElementById) {
    obj = document.getElementById(objId);
    if (opacity <= 100) { //function calls itself if the opacity is not yet over 100
      setOpacity(obj, opacity);
      opacity += 5; // the increment by which the opacity % changes. 
      window.setTimeout("fadeIn('"+objId+"',"+opacity+")", 50); //=> the opacity will change by the increment in the line above every X seconds where X is the lenght of the setTimeout
    }
    else {
    obj.style.removeAttribute('filter'); //IE bug
    }
  }
}

function fadeOut(objId,opacity) {
  if (document.getElementById) {
    obj = document.getElementById(objId);
    if (opacity >= 0) { //function calls itself if the opacity is not yet under zero
      setOpacity(obj, opacity);
      opacity -= 5; // the increment by which the opacity % changes. 
      window.setTimeout("fadeOut('"+objId+"',"+opacity+")", 50); //=> the opacity will change by the increment in the line above every X seconds where X is the lenght of the setTimeout
    }
    else {
    obj.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}


window.onload = function() {
    startFade('big-pic','in');
    window.setTimeout("startFade('whitediv_headings','out');",1400);
    window.setTimeout("startFade('gallery','in');",2800); //maybe change to a white div to present a choppy intro...?!
    window.setTimeout("startFade('whitediv_navbar','out');",2800);
    window.setTimeout("startFade('whitediv_text-right','out');",2800);
};

function fadeOutNoDisplay(objId,opacity) {
  if (document.getElementById) {
    document.getElementById(objId).onclick = null;
    document.getElementById(objId).onmouseover = null;
    document.getElementById(objId).onmouseout = null;
    obj = document.getElementById(objId);
    if (opacity >= 0) { //function calls itself if the opacity is not yet under zero
      setOpacity(obj, opacity);
      opacity -= 5; // the increment by which the opacity % changes. 
      window.setTimeout("fadeOutNoDisplay('"+objId+"',"+opacity+")", 50); //=> the opacity will change by the increment in the line above every X seconds where X is the lenght of the setTimeout
    }
    else {
    document.getElementById(objId).style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which browsers are "all browsers", and what is a good zoom level to test with? Maybe also add an image of the undesired "overlapping".

Comment: It's probably best for you go to http://www.kikbo.com/secret/about.html and look at it with different zooms.

moz, chrome, ie

Comment: The only thing I can see is this, in Chrome: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xNDLk.png - and something similar in Firefox 4. If that really is it, just forget about it. It's not a big deal.

Comment: Yeah exactly that. It looks worse once you start clicking the boxes which fade away to reveal information...thanks for the look and the pic thirtydot

Comment: [I saw other problems](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YVUW4.png), but not the problem you're complaining about... :)

Comment: hey sarnold...what are you talking about I can't get that to happen for me? what browser did you use?

Answer (score 0):

I changed everything from `float: left` to `position: absolute` and everything started to display properly, regardless of zoom level